# How to set vue-router navigation guards to route to child routes without getting an infinite loop?

Tags: vue-router

My routes have a parent path with children. How can I set a navigation guard on the parent route to route to the children without it triggering an infinite loop?

This beforeEnter loops as it is called when I navigate to 'path/parent/child1' or 'path/parent/child2'

```js
{
  path: "path/parent",
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    if (checkSomethingInDB) {
      if (checkSomethingElseInDB) {
        next()
      } else {
        next({ name: 'child1' })
      }
    } else {
      next({ name: 'child2' })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come to that problem recently, when trying to acces a child route, and having a navigation guard in the parent route.

Solved checking if the numbers of mathces of the routes to where I am going is equal to 1, meaning I'm on the first level of the route, or the parent.
If the results is greater than 1 , it means I'm going to a child route.

I can also use that logic to implement specific navigation guards through childs.

```js
path: "/",
beforeEnter: async (to) => {
  if (to.matched.length == 1) { /* Guard only for the parent */ }
},
children: [
  { path: "/children1", },
  { 
    path: "/children2", 
    beforeEnter: async (to) => {
      if (to.matched.length == 2) { /* Guard only for this child */ }
    },
    children: [
      { path: "/children21", },
      { path: "/children22", },
    ]
  },
]
```